# Why physical force and power in the definition of violence

Tags: terminology

I've been working my way through the concept of violence.  I started with the definition provided by the WHO as a reasonable starting place:

> Violence is “the intentional use of physical force or power,
> threatened or actual, against  oneself, or against a group or
> community that either results in or has a high likelihood of resulting
> in injury, death, psychological harm, maldevelopment or deprivation.”
>
> -WHO global consultation on violence and health, 1996.

Working through phrase by phrase, I started looking at "... physical force or power..."  Power appears to refer to things such as social power, where one can influence how others act.  These seem quite different.  While I can see why both of these would fit into the definition, they don't seem to have an easy to pin down common denominator.

Why do they include specifically physical force and power as two separate elements in the definition?  Is there a common denominator, or are these viewed as the two paths to violence, excluding others?  Or is there perhaps a historical reason?

Comment: I believe they are saying "physical force or [physical] power," i.e. they aren't including all forms of power, just physical forms.

Comment: @causative That would make sense, although it leads me to the follow up of drawing a line between physical force and physical power.

Comment: Well... force times distance is work, and if something is *powerful* it can do a lot of work (or harm if you like) in a short time, which sounds like violence to me.

Comment: Because they want to cover [psychological violence](https://www.coe.int/en/web/gender-matters/psychological-violence) that "*includes threatening conduct which lacks physical violence or verbal elements, for example, actions that refer to former acts of violence, or purposeful ignorance and neglect of another person*". The common denominator is causing severe harm, which can be both (narrowly) physical or psychological.

Comment: @conifold so that either/or could be seen as "everything" from a perspective of dualism?

Comment: I do not think "either/or" there refers to physical/psychological, it refers to "results in / has a high likelihood of" harm of both kinds. And it seems viewpoint neutral to me, idealists, dualists or physicalists recognize harms of both kinds, at least in the colloquial sense.